# Issues changing CSV column type to date in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I encountered some trouble changing cell types in LibreOffice Calc from text to dates.

This happens when I import a CSV file. The import into rows and columns works fine. However, the dates are not recognized as such. When I try to change the cell type manually via "Format Cells..." to the appropriate date format Calc only prepends a `'` to the cell.

Example: The text "19.03.24" reads "'19.03.24" after manually changing the cell format to date.

I suppose there is some "hidden" setting that prevents me from changing the cell type.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/trouble-formatting-date-cells-in-calc/1880).

However, any comment on how that magic worked or why date formatting fails will still be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

[CSV, **c**omma **s**eparated **v**alues,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) though other separator characters, such as *tab*, are also used, has *no concept of specific format,* not as date, currency, Boolean or other data type.

All data in a CSV is treated as numeric, [unless the data field contains specific characters](https://b-greve.gitbook.io/beginners-guide-to-clean-data/common-csv-problems/quotation-characters), e.g., begins with a single quote, ', or is surrounded by double quotes, ".

Look at the CSV data in a text editor. If there are quotes at the beginning of a field, MS Excel, LibreOffice Calc and other spreadsheets treat that as *text*.

To remove initial single quotes, use the text editor to search and replace them. If there are *internal* quotes to be preserved,

- Search on the separator and quote, e.g., `,'`, and replace with just the separator, e.g., `,`.
- For the *initial* field of a line, search on the end-of-line sequence and quote, e.g., `\r\n'`, using regex, and replace with just the separator, e.g., `,`.